# Android: How can I change icons size in Action Bar Tabs?

Tags: android, icons, material-design, android-tabs

I created an Action Bar Tabs activity for my project. I used 3 tabs and I added some icons. But the icons are shown in a small size, even if I downloaded them in 48dp.

[image]

My code is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

```
final private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_photo_library,
        R.drawable.ic_chat,
        R.drawable.ic_people
};

private void setupTabsIcons() {

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);

}
```

**How could I change the size of the icons?** I also have a FloatingActionButton with the same problem. The icon inside it is small.

Comment: just add tab youself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add Tab you self.

```
TabLayout layout = new TabLayout(TestActvt.this);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom,null);
view.findViewById(R.id.img).setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
TabLayout.Tab tab = layout.newTab().setCustomView(view);
layout.addTab(tab);
```

FloatingActionButton only has 2 size : mini or normal and Iamge in them has fixed size.

Comment: I am using ``SectionsPagerAdapter`` to manage tabs and ``@Override public Fragment getItem(int position)`` to show the fragment in every tab. I think your answer is irrelevant. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: TabLayout.getChildAt(0) is  the Strip .Then strip.getChildAt(n) is the tabview .Then you can set layoutparams like normal view. Use  instance of  to get the type of view.

Comment: I think I understand now. But I dont have a custom made tabs layout. I created one with support:design library. Here is my code http://hastebin.com/baxupapogi.java for the Activity and the layout http://hastebin.com/ibuhenayej.xml

Comment: No what I said is support:design library,not a custom .

Comment: just replace   tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager) with addTab one by one . and add  setOnTabSelectListener to setCurrentItem of ViewPager.

Comment: I'm going to bed now.Try debug and use getChildAt() of TabLayout,and you can find how to change style of tabView or just use addTab to add tabview one by one.

Comment: Got it and it works. I made a custom layout with an ImageView and used ``setBackgroundResource()``, not ``setImageResource()``. Thank you sir for your patience:)

Comment: Using this approach doesn't allow me to set text. I am in a situation where I use Icon and Text for the tab item as requested. Setting text programatically will not do anything at all if I set an icon!