# Android: How to add custom tab to TabbedActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have this activity:

I created it with New Activity->Tabbed Activity in Android Studio 1.5

[image]

They provided me with the following code which is generated when you create this kind of activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Here is the custom code

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null);
    view.findViewById(R.id.custom_tab_imageView).setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

I wanted to add a new custom tab besides the three existing so I created custom_tab.xml that contains an ImageView with id=custom_tab_imageView and added the following to onCreate():

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null);
  view.findViewById(R.id.custom_tab_imageView).setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view);
tabLayout.addTab(tab);
```

In SECTION 1,2,3 there is a PlaceholderFragment shown that say "Hello World from section..."

**How do I need to modify the SectionsPagerAdapter in order to show "Hello world from section 4" when user tap the custom tab?** Or how do I make the adapter recognize it as the fourth tab?

Comment: Modify your `SectionsPagerAdapter` 's` getCount` method to `return` 4.

Comment: @Trivial I already did that, but it only add an empty tab between SECTION 3 and my custom tab.

Comment: Try to set the adapter after adding a tab. I think it will work.

Comment: @Trivial I know each method and I understand what it does but I don't know how to set the adapter properly. Could you help me with some code or an example?

Comment: M sure this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance("Gallery");
            case 1:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance("Chat");
            case 2:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance("People");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        /*switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Gallery";
            case 1:
                return "Chat";
            case 2:
                return "People";
        }*/

        // Return null to display only icons
        return null;
    }
}
```

Create a custom tab and call `setCustomView()` method:

```
private void setupTabIcons() {

    View view0 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    view0.findViewById(R.id.custom_imageView).setBackgroundResource(tabIcons[0]);

    View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    view1.findViewById(R.id.custom_imageView).setBackgroundResource(tabIcons[1]);

    View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    view2.findViewById(R.id.custom_imageView).setBackgroundResource(tabIcons[2]);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(view1);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(view2);

}
```

In `onCreate()` call `setupTabIcons()` and that's it. You have 3 custom tabs connected to 3 fragments for your TabbedActivity.

Answer (score 0):

All the magic happens in FragmentPagerAdapter.

In short,

Override `getCount()` method to define number of tabs.

Define titles of each tab in `getPageTitle()` method

and of course, `getItem()` to return Fragment for ViewPager - and link it's position with TabLayout.

In your case, to add a new tab...

1. [Create a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)
2. Add the following `case` in `switch` block of `getPageTitle()` method to add Tab at the last position:

   ```
   case 3:
       return 'SECTION 4';
   ```
3. return the `Fragment` from `getItem()` method when position is `3`:

   ```
   if (position == 3) {
       return <new instance of your Fragment>;
   }
   ```

---

**Update:**

Well, how about this?

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
    }
});
```

If this is what you want, then you need to modify your code. Almost all of it.

Comment: I already tried that. This is the simple case if you dont have a custom tab. It works but it is not an answer for my problem. I have a custom layout with and ImageView because I want to modify the size of the icon in tabs. So I need to add 3 custom tabs to the layout and connect them to fragments.

Comment: In that case, just set a click listener on tab and set ViewPager's current item using `setCurrentItem()` method.

Comment: Could you update your answer with an example or some code? I dont fully understand how could I do what you said.

Comment: No. Now I can't click on the custom tab. It goes to the SECTION 3 and the custom tab is not clickable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to set a custom tab view along with Image and text

Create an xml layout named `custom_tab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/tab_label"
    android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"/>
```

Render custom_tab.xml layout in each tab using below lines of code.

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("ONE");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```

Complete class code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("ONE");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("TWO");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_call, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText("THREE");
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. But the icon size is very small. That't why I need a custom layout with an ImageView, to change the icon size as I want. See my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068329/android-how-can-i-change-icons-size-in-action-bar-tabs

Comment: okay, so try to set adapter after the tab is added. Have you tried that ?

Comment: How to set it with my custom tab?

Comment: @Cristi see the code. May you can make a way around for only image.

Comment: I think custom si the only solution if you want different sizes for icons. Thanks for trying to help me!